# any algebraic solution for counting paths in a hex tiling?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider an undirected planar graph whose nodes are arranged as a hexagonal tiling confined to a circle. In large graphs their mean degree thus approaches 6. Given two identified nodes on the perimeter $p_1$ and $p_2$, I want to know how many unique simple paths there are $<p_1, ..., p_2>$.

Of course algorithms such as DFS and branch-and-bound can be deployed on this problem. Still, with these constraints - nearly all nodes having exactly 6 neighbors in a planar graph with a round perimeter - is there an algebraic approach?

Comment: There is basically no hope that there is a nice solution to this. You could make the problem simpler by removing the boundary conditions (maybe embed a totally uniform 6-regular graph on a torus or sphere), but then you're still counting self-avoiding walks. See [these slides](http://www.unige.ch/~smirnov/slides/slides-saw.pdf), which discuss self-avoiding walks on the hexagonal lattice.

Comment: thanks, Eric. i imagined that knowing about the distribution of path lengths (exactly one shortest path the length of the diameter, many longest paths whose lengths are equal to the area, etc.) plus maybe using the rectangular model in "Algebraic Techniques for Enumerating Self-
Avoiding Walks on the Square Lattice" could be a way forward. thanks for leading me to the "self-avoiding" terminology, that helped.